# Caliburn Micro with TreeView ContextMenu target does not exist

Tags: wpf, telerik, treeview, contextmenu, caliburn.micro

It seems (from other posts with similar problems) that I am trying to bind the target to an element which doesn't exist in the same visual tree. I have a ContextMenu on the 3rd level in the TreeView, and am trying to set an action to execute a method on the ViewModel via the Tag of the parent element (TextBlock), but can't get it to work.

The XAML is:

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="FeatureTemplate">
    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"> 
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Tag="{Binding DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
        <telerik:RadContextMenu.ContextMenu >
        <telerik:RadContextMenu cal:Action.TargetWithoutContext="{Binding Path=PlacementTarget.Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
         cal:Message.Attach="[Event Opened] = [Action ContextMenuOpened($source)]">               
        <telerik:RadMenuItem Header="Export" cal:Message.Attach="[Event Click]=[Action ContextMenuClick($source)]"/>
        </telerik:RadContextMenu>
        </telerik:RadContextMenu.ContextMenu>
    </TextBlock>
</Grid>
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>

<HierarchicalDataTemplate 
x:Key="FormTemplate" 
ItemTemplate="{StaticResource FeatureTemplate}" 
ItemsSource="{Binding List}">
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Image Source="{Binding Image}" Width="32" Height="32" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,3"/>
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Name}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5"/>
</Grid>
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>

<HierarchicalDataTemplate  
    x:Key="JobTemplate"  
ItemTemplate="{StaticResource FormTemplate}" 
ItemsSource="{Binding List}">
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>

<telerik:RadTreeView Name="TreeView1" 
 Grid.Row="2" 
 cal:Message.Attach="[Event SelectionChanged] = [Action SetSelectedItem($this.SelectedItem)]" 
 Background="White" 
 ItemsSource="{Binding AvailableData}" 
 ItemTemplate="{StaticResource JobTemplate}" 
 telerik:AnimationManager.IsAnimationEnabled="False" >
</telerik:RadTreeView>
```

ViewModel code:
    public void ContextMenuOpened(FrameworkElement source){}

I get the error that ContextMenuOpened target is not found.
Any help or suggestions would be much appreciated.